# Power Query not find field in OData Feed

Tags: excel, odata, powerquery

Have problem with OData Feed (same in PBI and in Excel). Web Service have that column name, but can't load it. It returns with error "Details: "OData: The property 'XXXX' does not exist on type 'YYYY'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open type.".

The funny thing - if i use "?$select=" without choosing that column, then Excel load that column as empty with header named 'XXXX' only:)
Any advices?

Comment: What's the source or where is the feed coming from? Is the field in question a Calculated one? Do you have any query options set like `[Implementation="2.0",OmitValues = ODataOmitValues.Nulls,ODataVersion = 4]`?

Comment: @SamNseir source is Ms Dynamics BC. No, it;s not calculated and feed has only Implementation=2.0. If i using feed as web source, not as OData feed (Web service is OData feed, like http://xxxxx/BC/ODataV4/Company('')/ProdOrderList?$top=5000), then i have no errors and all works perfect

Comment: What's the field type of the field in question? Is it an Array field? If so, see [Array fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/fin-ops-core/dev-itpro/data-entities/odata#array-fields)

Comment: @SamNseir Not sure, but think so it's cell type, because other sources transforms as table with cells